# Why libc dependency despite of -nostdlib

Tags: gcc, clang, shared-libraries, llvm-clang, libc

I would like to control dependency to libc during my shared library building.

So, I've introduced -nostdlib in command line (with clang 8 or gcc 9; it's the same).

This works if I do not link my lib against some other shared library (libossp-uuid, to name it).

But not with -lossp-uuid.

```
cc -fPIC -shared -nostdlib -olibmain.so   main.c -L/usr/local/lib -lossp-uuid -I/usr/local/include
```

ldd shows a dependency to libc.so.7.

```
ldd ./libmain.so
./libmain.so:
        libossp-uuid.so.16 => /usr/local/lib/libossp-uuid.so.16 (0x80066f000)
        libc.so.7 => /lib/libc.so.7 (0x80024a000)
```

The question is why I can't. Is there a workaround.

Thank you very much for any smart suggestion.
This is a great mystery for me.

Comment: Can't reproduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency appears to stem from `libossp-uuid.so.16`. You will have to build that library with `-nostdlib` as well.